# MS SQL Server connection with JasperReports

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, jasper-reports, ireport

Please tell me how to set a connection with MS SQL Server 2005 and JasperReports.

Please tell me the steps for the connection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use jdbc driver for connection with MS SQL Server.

Connection string looks like:

> jdbc:sqlserver://[serverName[\instanceName][:portNumber]][;property=value[;property=value]]

You car read about each parameter [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).

The sample connection string:

> jdbc:sqlserver://server:port;DatabaseName=dbname

The sample code of connecting with [JasperReports API](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/index.html) to MS SQL Database:

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=test";
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "userName", "password");

Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportSource);
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, connection);

JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, targetFileName);
```

You can download `JDBC Driver 2.0` [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=2505) or `JDBC Driver 3.0` [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=21599).

Comment: That's a pretty nice answer for a pretty imprecise question.

Comment: Microsoft JDBC Driver 6.0 for SQL Server  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11774